# Batch file numbered save files

Tags: batch-file, export, scheduled-tasks

I'm using a scheduled task to run a batch file for exporting backups. Within the command for exporting it uses "FILE=filename". I gave it a name but how can I make it numbered so it doesn't overwrite? (e.g. file1, file2, file3).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you are in the same directory:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "file_name_pattern=file"
for  %%a in (file*) do (
    set "file_name=%%~na"
)

set "last_file_number=!file_name:%file_name_pattern%=!"

echo last file number : !last_file_number!

set /a next_file_number=last_file_number

set next_file=!file_name_pattern!%next_file_number%

echo next file : %next_file%

endlocal
```

A solution with `FOR /L`

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set "file_name_pattern=file"


set init=1

for /l %%n in (1;1;10000) do (
    echo %%n
    if not exist "!file_name_pattern!%%n" (

        set last_file_number=%%n
        goto :break_for
        rem
    )
)
:break_for


echo last file number : !last_file_number!

set /a next_file_number=last_file_number+1

set next_file=!file_name_pattern!%next_file_number%

echo next file : %next_file%

endlocal
```

Comment: will work fine, as long as there are less than 10 numbered files.

Comment: @Stephan - damn. Forgot about that.Will include a call of `DIR` or rather `FOR /L`

Comment: ahm - I don't want to tease you, but your `FOR /L` solution: if you found the first "not-existent" file, there is no need to add one...

Comment: So where would my export command be placed within the code?
e.g. exp user/pass FILE=file.dmp

Thanks

Comment: @npocmaka the command is as shown in my previous comment:
exp user/pass FILE="file.dmp"